# How to insert values from column A to Column C based on a condition on Column B in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert values into df['ColumnC'] as 1/df['ColumnA'] if df['ColumnB'] == 'string1' OR 'string2' OR' string3'.

Please help in obtaining values after calculating the inverse of Column A into Column C if Column B is 'string1' or 'string2' or 'string3'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
m = df['ColumnB'].isin(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'])
df.loc[m, 'ColumnC'] = 1 / df.loc[m, 'ColumnA']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ColumnA  ColumnB   ColumnC
0        2  string1  0.500000
1        3  string2  0.333333
2        4  string3  0.250000
3        5  string4       NaN
```